# Android Eclipse v.20 not generating R.java

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-resources, r.java-file

Hello my partner and I have been working on this problem and doing research for the last two weeks on this problem. We are using the Android version 5.0.1 and it will not generate our resource file(r.java). 
We think it may have something to do with these errors we are getting upon creating the project. Any help would be much appreciated. The errors follow this paragraph.

```
[2014-12-23 13:01:39 - jcandroid!] C:\Users\Jacob\workspace\jcandroid!\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-12-23 13:01:39 - jcandroid!] 
[2014-12-23 13:01:39 - jcandroid!] C:\Users\Jacob\workspace\jcandroid!\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2014-12-23 13:01:39 - jcandroid!] 
[2014-12-23 13:01:39 - jcandroid!] C:\Users\Jacob\workspace\jcandroid!\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2014-12-23 13:01:39 - jcandroid!]
```

Comment: I think you need Android Studio at this point, as ADT is no longer supported nor is it the official IDE for Android development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing I notice is you have an exclamation mark ! in your project name. You should remove that because it could cause weird issues with tools.

Also check if your project is including the AppCompat library.

Follow the steps to download and install the AppCompat library as instructed [on the Android Developers site](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html).

Make sure you add the library to your project in Eclipse by right-clicking on the project then selecting Properties -> Android. In Library, click Add then select the appcompat_v7 library.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked I looked at the page multiple times but overlooked the answer that was in front of my eyes.